# Book for topology of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

What is the best publicly available source (book or lecture series) to study topological properties of the space of square real matrices, $M_n(\mathbb{R})$? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: topologically it's just $\mathbb R^{n^2}$. What are you expecting?

Comment: Like I want to look into its subsets which are compact or dense or open etc

Comment: Those properties are purely topological, so they can be handled by studying the topology on $\mathbb R^k$.

Comment: Tapp's "Matrix Groups for Undergraduates" or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

As other commenters have pointed out $M_n(\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, so there's no interesting strictly topological properties of real matrix algebras.

For questions such as "What are the topological properties of various subspaces of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ (e.g. nonsingular matrices, orthogonal matrices, etc.)" any of the standard books on matrix analysis (e.g. Horn and Johnson) should have much of what you want, albeit not necessarily in topological language. The fact that nonsingular matrices are dense in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ will be stated as, for example, something like.

> For any matrix $A$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $E\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such $\|E\| < \epsilon$ such that $A + E$ is nonsingular.

So there is a certain amount of translation required between analytic characterizations and topological ones.